# Is this express-session authentication method secure

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

Im not sure if this express-session auth method is secure. I encrypt the password using `bcryptjs` and after encrypting I set the `req.session.isLoggedIn = true` in `admin.js` and later check it in `events.js` by using an if statement. Is the if statement method in `events.js` secure or somehow breachable? Is there an better option?
I'm using handlebars to render the web pages.

admin.js

```
bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password).then((doMatch) => {
    console.log(doMatch);
    //Check if password match
    if (doMatch) {
      //setting the isLoggedIn value
      req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
      //Events is the route that requires authentication
      return res.redirect('/events');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

events.js

```
Router.get('/', (req, res) => {
//Checking the if the loggedIn value is true
if (req.session.isLoggedIn) {
Event.find({}, (err, events) => {
  res.render('events', {
    prods: events,
    pageTitle: 'Events',
    path: '/events',
    hasProducts: events.length > 0
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
} else {
  console.log('User not authenticated');
  res.status(404).send({error: 'not authorized!'});
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best method you should take a look at : http://www.passportjs.org/

They have a good documentation about authentication strategies and registration also many other methods(Facebook login, Twitter...) also there is many tutorials on how you can implement Passport.js

Hope it helps you !